# How to Correctly Import Python Modules and Avoid Import Errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I have a custom python module I'm working on and am confused how I should import modules into other modules.  I want to use bits and pieces of some modules within others and keep getting an error: `ImportError: cannot import name NameOfModule`

I'm assuming there's some sort of circular reference that's causing the issue but I'm not sure if I need to add something to `__init__.py`, or if there's a specific way of importing the modules into each other, or if I should change my folder structure?

If I want to be able to use some function from `mod1.py` within `mod2.py` how should I go about setting up the import statements?

My current folder structure is:

```
FolderName
  -__init__.py
  -mod1.py
  -mod2.py
  -mod3.py
  -mod4.py
```

Sample code:

- `__init__.py` is empty
- mod1.py: `from . import mod2`
- mod2.py: `from . import mod1`

Comment: In `mod2.py`: `import mod1`? To be frank, doesn't look like you need the `__init__.py`.

Comment: Please post the actual code, preferably an MCVE [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve], that is generating the error.

Comment: original post updated

Comment: issue resolved...by using `from . import x` it seems to assume you are going up a folder, where in my case my modules are at the same root, so simply using `import x` fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should be using relative imports for files within the current module, like so:

```
from . import mod2
```

Or:

```
from .mod2 import foo
```

And unless you have a VERY good reason, you should be using Python 3.

Comment: specific software this will be used for uses 2.7.x